# A quick puzzle to keep your brain busy on a Friday... or is it?

Tags: riddle, word

I am the one what did the did and the one what knows what did the did.

I am one and the same, but distinct and separate.

The situations I create are also quite tense.

I am no Cyrano, but if you're looking for me, you'll find ten letters.

Hint #1:

> The answer to this puzzle is not a person. It is an adjective in both forms.

Comment: Hint added. This wasn't supposed to be a challenging puzzle!

Comment: ...or was it?${}$

Comment: "did the did" or "did the deed"?

Comment: It's a little bit of wordplay, it just means the word describes the person who did something and the person who knows that someone did what was done, and might be looking for said person. It's actually very hard to create clues that aren't giveaways for this puzzle. You use this word, and words that are connected to it, on a very regular basis.

Comment: I still have no idea how to parse that first sentence, but I can think of words with two adjective meanings.

Comment: As promised, the answer is now given. You guys can breathe a sigh of frustrated relief now, I'll see if I can't post another puzzle today. >:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the one what did the did and the one what knows what did the did.

> The person who has committed an evil, unethical, or immoral act is __________. The person who is looking for the _______ is also __________. It's often said that detectives are __________ of everyone they meet.

I am one and the same, but distinct and separate.

> Both words are spelled the same, are adjectives, but describe two opposing people in the same situation.

The situations I create are also quite tense.

> Virtually all drama involves someone being __________. You will be hard pressed to find a crime drama that does not refer to someone as a _______ or __________.

I am no Cyrano, but if you're looking for me, you'll find ten letters.

> The word you're looking for has ten letters.

The word is:

> SUSPICIOUS

And you often use words directly related to it such as

> SUSPECT or SUSPICION.